# Recentering D3 force layout diagram on node click

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I am trying to create a force diagram that gets re-centered on click.

I am following [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093130) as a base:

[image]

I tried to adjust the click function to set `d.fixed=true` and also assign fixed points for `d.x` and `d.y`.

However, I need to turn `d.fixed=false` for all the other nodes. Also, the node does not transition to the center on click.

My question is how do I set all other fixed properties to false and then redraw the force diagram with the new center?

I have prepared an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5dJaA/):

[image]

The click function is fairly straightforward:

```
  function click(d) {
        d.fixed=true;
        d.x=10;
        d.y=10;
        update();
    }
```

I tried adding this to the function:

```
root.forEach(function (d) { d.fixed = false; });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the nodes using `force.nodes()` and iterate to set the `fixed` attribute to `false`.

```
force.nodes().forEach(function(d) { d.fixed = false; });
```

and then update the graph. I forked your example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pnavarrc/8xQD4/2/) and added a double click listener that restart the force layout. Regards,

Comment: That is really helpful!  I guess my only question is how do I perform the transform correctly so that the node that I click transitions to center smoothly and the line follows suit? I forked again [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8xQD4/3/)  The doubleclick is awesome!

Comment: You can compute the position of the nodes (d.x and d.y) without updating the position of the circles, labels and links, and then update the position of the graphic elements using a transition. If the answer was helpful, please mark it as answered so other users know that is already answered. If you need more help with the transition, consider asking that in a new thread.

Answer (score 4):

A few things, in the order I approached the problem.  Here's the [final fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5dJaA/1/) if you want to follow along.

First, your `update()` method does a lot more than just update the position of the nodes; it recalculates the whole tree.  It's overkill for what you're trying to do, and while in the end it turned out to not be the source of the problem, I'd still recommend just using [`force.resume()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-resume) to get the timer ticking and the nodes moving again.

Second, you were on the right track with adding a `forEach` statement to turn off the former fixed nodes.  But `forEach` works on arrays, and `root` is an object.  So either reuse the `flatten` method (slow) or do as @Pablo suggested and use force.nodes() to get the nodes as an array (better).

Third, and this took a bit to figure out: Once you set a node to be "fixed", the force layout ignores any new d.x and d.y values, resetting them back to d.px and d.py (the previous values).  (I assume this is so that if the node is dragged, it will automatically jump back to its fixed position).  So to move it to be fixed where you want it to be, you have to set the "previous" values, not the new values.  The only problem is that this causes an immediate jump in position, instead of a smooth movement.  You might want to add in a transition for that one node (to make it look like it's being dragged to the centre) before calling `force.resume()`.

Comment: This is fantastic!  I have learned so much from both you! I may need a bit of help with transition the center node smoothly (your explanation of why you have to set `d.px` and `d.py` makes perfect sense), but I'll open a new question.  Thank you both!

Comment: I don't see a new question yet, so I'll post this here:  I've got a basic transition going on, although it's not super elegant (it only transitions the node, not the links; and the node doesn't push any other nodes out of its way while transitioning).  I also switched it so you have to double-click to centre the node; otherwise the centring routine was being triggered if you dragged a node as well (the mouseup also triggers a click event, you'd need extra code to distinguish between the too).  http://jsfiddle.net/5dJaA/2/

Comment: yes I haven't created a new question yet. I was working on the data side for a bit before I came back to this.  I took a look at what you wrote (thanks again!) and played around with it a bit.  I am thinking that I need some way to draw a line for `(d.x,d.y)` to `(width/2,height/2)` and divide this up into several small steps and then loop through each step and update the position of `d.px` and `d.py`?  I am still a bit confused how to update the links.  Again, I really appreciate the help, I am learning a ton.

Comment: I know this is wrong, but I tried something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/5dJaA/5/) where I compute the slope and get new x and y values based on that.  I also added back in the bit to ignore dragging for single click.

Comment: I think this is something like what you were going for: http://jsfiddle.net/5dJaA/7/; moves the node almost to the centre, then turns on the force layout.  I used the `tick()` method to update both circle and line positions, but added in a transition to make it smooth.  To really finesse, replace the arbitrary 0.8 value with something calculated to be one node-radius away from the centre.