# multiple force layouts same page

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I am attempting to create a force layout where not all the nodes connect with links.  Additionally, I got some terrific help with centering a node when it is clicked (reference to question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20860660/recenter-force-diagram-on-click)).

I would like to incorporate the two together, but am a bit stuck.

I created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CvF2L/) where I modified the original data where not every node has a link; however, as you can see from the Fiddle, only a single node is drawn and nothing else is displayed.

The data looks something like this:

```
[
                {   "name": "cluster",
                    "children": [
                        {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
                        {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
                        {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
                        {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "graph",
                    "children": [
                        {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},
                        {"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731},
                        {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840},
                        {"name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914},
                        {"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "optimization",
                    "children": [
                        {"name": "AspectRatioBanker", "size": 7074}
                    ]
                }
]
```

I am not certain, but it seems to me when I try:
`var nodes = flatten(root)` this is going to cause some problems.

I found some examples where multiple force layouts are shown in a single svg, but I am thinking this is going to cause some problems when I re-center by clicking.

Comment: The force layout has no problem if nodes aren't attached to each other; as you suspected, the problem is in the `flatten(root)` method, which assumes that you are passing in a single object that is the root of the tree, and that this object contains a "children" property.  Instead, you are passing in an array.  Of course, the array's children property is null, so no other nodes get created.  See if you can figure out how to re-write the flatten method to flatten each object in the input array into an array of nodes, and then concatenate them all together.

Comment: [Hints](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Iterating_over_arrays)

Comment: Thanks again!  I realized that last night when I was playing around with your fiddle from the other question.  Seriously, thanks a ton.