# How to pan to a node using d3's force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to focus on a node when it is searched for by name. I am trying to do this using a recenter method....

```
zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([.05, 10])
        .on("zoom", zoomed);
svg = d3.select("#graph")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("height", height)
        .attr("width", width)
        .call(zoom);
....
function zoomed(sel) {
    zoomBase(d3.event.translate , d3.event.scale);
}
function zoomBase(translate, scale){
    zoom.scale(scale);
    zoom.translate(translate);
    container.attr("transform", "translate(" + translate + ")scale(" + scale + ")");
}
function recenter(node){
    var node = findNodeByName(node);
    if(zoom.scale() < 0.5){
        zoom.scale(0.5);
    }
    zoom.translate([node.x, node.y]); // Math seems to be wrong here
    container.attr("transform", "translate(" + translate + ")scale(" + zoom.scale() + ")");
}
```

The problem is that when I am over the node in question and search for it my location shows up as `[-2246.3690822841745, -846.6411913027562]` but when I get the x and y off of the actual node I get `[4346.868560310511, 1950.790521658118]` considering I am over top of the node, is there some math or something I need here?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20860660/recentering-d3-force-layout-diagram-on-node-click and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225069/zooming-to-a-clicked-node-on-a-d3-force-directed-graph

Comment: I have a hunch that there is a transform on the main group(which contain all teh nodes) thus when you take the node .x and node.y for translating it to center you didn't consider the translate of its parent g group. But like I said its just a hunch, can confirm and suggest a solution if you put the code on a fiddle.

Comment: I am not sure, added a little more. I did notice the zoom function is registered on the SVG element instead of the container but I assume this is normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lars was right this is the answer...

```
zoom.translate([width / 2 - zoom.scale() * node.x, height / 2 - zoom.scale() * node.y])
```

To break this doesn a bit

```
width / 2 (go to middle) 
- 
zoom.scale() * node.x (move middle to the scaled x)
```