# d3.js v4 move viewport to specific node

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I use d3.js v4 to build force-directed graph just like in the basic example. I've also created input field, where user can type the node name. Then I search the matching `circle` element like so:

```js
findNode(name) {
    let theNode = this.d3Svg.selectAll('circle').filter(function(d) {
      return d.name == name;
    });
}
```

After that I want to move viewport to the `foundNode`. How can I do that?

Tried this:
`this.d3.zoom().translateTo(theNode, theNode.x, theNode.y);`
but nothing happens. Here is what `console.log('theNode: ',theNode)` says:

[image: thisNode]

I've also found [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31011004/how-to-pan-to-a-node-using-d3s-force-layout), but some older version of d3 is used there.

Comment: @Ian I'm new to d3, so I do not know what to do

Comment: Are you receiving any error when you try `this.d3.zoom().translateTo(theNode, theNode.x, theNode.y);`?

Are you trying this inside `findNode` or outside of it? Since you are using `let`, `theNode` as a variable will not be available outside of `findNode` due to `let`'s limitation of scope.

Comment: @223seneca inside of findNode(). I'm able to change the node radius and color though. So the node is found correctly, I think.

Comment: You didn't answer my question about the error. Try checking the error console. It wouldn't make sense for it to just not work but not throw an error either. Also, within `findNode`, add `console.log('theNode: ',theNode);` and post what it says.

Comment: @223seneca pardon, no error in console. I've also updated the question.

Comment: seems like I need [this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/b783fbb2e673561d214e09c7fb5cedee)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://bl.ocks.org/iamkevinv/0a24e9126cd2fa6b283c6f2d774b69a2) is the solution. 
The following code brings the viewport to the center:

```js
svg.transition()
          .duration(750)
          .call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.translate([width / 2, height / 2]));
```